# How can I disable AOT in angular2?

Tags: angular, build, angular5, angular6, angular2-aot

I got something like this:

```
ng build --prod --no-aot
```

But I am not able to understand what is the difference between

```
ng build --prod
```

and

```
ng build --prod --no-aot
```

Comment: `ng build -prod -aot false`

Comment: See this to understand what `--prod` means https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/build.md#--dev-vs---prod-builds

Answer (score 17):

#### Update: For Angular 6+

Use the following command to disable AOT mode:

```
$ ng build --prod --aot=false --build-optimizer=false
```

Answer (score 4):

Just run command `ng build -prod -aot=false`. This will disable the aot compiler.

Answer (score 3):

The flag `--prod` does the AOT compilation by default. If you want to build without AOT then simply run `ng build` only without any flag.

Comment: I just want to know that what will be the effect on application?

Comment: With AOT, the browser downloads a pre-compiled version of the application. The browser loads executable code so it can render the application immediately, without waiting to compile the app first.

Comment: Just to point out here that if you skip --prod then code is not uglified, prod environment variables are ignored, service workers are also ignored. The recommended way to avoid aot is by doing ng build -prod -aot=false