# Enable production mode without AOT: Angular 4

Tags: angular

I am currently working on an application which is scheduled to go live soon. The problem is that I have to do a fair amount of cleanup for AOT, because when I run the following:

```
ng build --prod
```

it gives me error as my code is not fulfilling the requirements for AOT (example: not using service object directly in templates, etc.).
So is there way to enable prod mode with AOT to get all the good stuff like treeshaking, minification, uglify, etc. that Angular prod mode offers and just leave AOT for the time being?

NOTE: I’m considering enabling the prod mode in main.ts file and not on my local machine, using the following method:

```
enableProdMode();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I disable AOT in angular2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45814758/how-can-i-disable-aot-in-angular2)

Comment: This is not a duplicate. See my updated post.

Comment: I don't understand how your edit makes it not a duplicate. Could you explain why the other question doesn't help?

Comment: The post you mentioned is talking about building the app in prod mode on a local machine. But I’m talking about enabling prod mode on a production server.

Comment: How is the production server different in that you wouldn't be able to use `-aot=false`?

Answer (score 0):

> So is there way to enable prod mode with AOT to get all the good stuff
>   like treeshaking, minification, uglify, etc. that Angular prod mode
>   offers and just leave AOT for the time being?

You can migrate from Angular CLI to Webpack and tweak it accordingly for
 (local, development, production).
Since Angular CLI v1.0 there’s the “eject” feature, that allows you to extract the`webpack` config file and manipulate it as you wish.

Run `ng eject` so Angular CLI generates the webpack.config.js file.
Run `npm install` so the new dependencies generated by CLI are satisfied
**Guide**
 **[Angular CLI to webpack](https://medium.com/@s2dent/from-angular-cli-to-webpack-2-and-other-production-solutions-with-examples-f127abe06842)
[Production configuration for webpack](https://angular.io/guide/webpack#production-configuration)**

**PS** The Angular CLI hides the underlying complexity, once you eject, you have to deal with this complexity.